# regexp to replace several parts of a line

Tags: regex

I have a file with each line written like this :

```
m.187 g.187  ORF g.187 m.187 type:internal len:115 (+) Ph1000_1/1_1.000_345:1-348(+) m.189 g.189  ORF g.189 m.189 type:internal len:125 (+) Ph1007_1/1_1.000_376:1-378(+) m.104 g.104  ORF g.104 m.104 type:internal len:354 (+) Pu1004_1/1_1.000_1062:1-1065(+) m.147 g.147  ORF g.147 m.147 type:internal len:150 (+) Te1003_1/1_1.000_451:1-453(+)
```

it represents a list of genes IDs, but I want to simplify each of these lines : for example,if I take the first ID,

```
m.187 g.187  ORF g.187 m.187 type:internal len:115 (+) Ph1000_1/1_1.000_345:1-348(+)
```

- replace the part `m.187 g.187  ORF g.187 m.187 type:internal len:115 (+)` by a '`>`'
- replace and the part `:1-348(+)` by nothing

In order to keep only this :

```
>Ph1000_1/1_1.000_345
```

Each line would become something like :

```
>Ph1000_1/1_1.000_345 >Ph1007_1/1_1.000_376 >Pu1004_1/1_1.000_1062 >Te1003_1/1_1.000_451
```

This is quite complex ; the regexp I write, for now, deletes more things that I want and keep only the last ID, correctly written:

```
sed -e 's/m.*[ ]([+])[ ]/>/g' -e 's/[:].*$//' $1
```

gives

```
>Ph1000_1/1_1.000_345
```

So I think I'm close to find the answer but I am kinda stuck here ... Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

**sed** approach:

```
sed -E 's/m\.[0-9]{3}[^()]+\(\+\)\s*/>/g; s/:\S+//g' file
```

The output:

```
>Ph1000_1/1_1.000_345 >Ph1007_1/1_1.000_376 >Pu1004_1/1_1.000_1062 >Te1003_1/1_1.000_451
```

---

- `-E` - enables extended regular expressions
- `s/m\.[0-9]{3}[^()]+\(\+\)\s*/>/g` - replaces all sections started with `m.<3 digits>` and ended with `(+)` with `>`

Comment: Works perfectly ! Thank you very much !

Comment: @Micawber, welcome, have you tried to accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -e 's/(m.*?\(\+\))/>/g; s/:[\d\W]+//g' file
```